# Where can i find j2ee 1.4 sdk update 1?

Tags: java

J2EE 1.4 SDK update 1 is required for my project. Goggled a lot but couldn't find it. So it would be great if any one have a link to download J2EE SDK update 1 specifically. If you know or find a link don't forget to forward me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried a newer version, i.e. the current Java 7 SDK?  Usually when a program says it requires a certain version of something, that's a *minimum* version, not a *maximum*.  The Java 7 SDK supports building and running programs written for older Java versions, such as 1.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the official releases from Oracle, check out the Oracle Java Archive:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/archive-139210.html

There you can find J2EE 1.4_03 SDK, I do not recall whether "03" was the first patch, but it sounds close enough:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-eesdk-419427.html#j2eesdk-1_4_03-oth-JPR